# Is it acceptable to use present perfect progressive in this example

Tags: continuous

He **has swum**  daily for several years, but his shoulder has been bothering  him recently

this is an answer of a test **has swum** 
The reason of present perfect simple is that swimming has been done for so many times that it has become a permanent thing

But would it be possible to change for present perfect pogressive to emphasize the duration  and that this action is ongoing

https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/presperf1c.html

Comment: It would sound awkward to use present perfect continuous in both clauses. The 2nd clause is in PPC because it acts as a contrast to the longer, more permanent situation descrived by "has swum for several years"

Comment: [Is it acceptable, and not "will it be acceptable", here]

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable.

His shoulder **has been bothering** him recently.- We lay emphasis on the **activity**. Here activity has not been finished. It is still happening.

He **has swum** daily for several years- We put emphasis on **completed action**, not the activity.

Answer (score 0):

"He's been swimming daily for several years" also works. The meaning is slightly different.

"He's swum daily" treats *swimming* as a recurring event.

"He's been swimming daily" treats *swimming daily* as a single process that has continued for years.

A native speaker might also say "he's gone swimming daily" instead. This is like "he's swum daily" but describes the action of *going swimming* (including e.g. traveling to the water) in addition to the swimming itself.

Comment: Re *gone swimming*:  not suitable if he's on the swim team, but suitable if it's a leisure activity.